# How to use a custom status command for a service in puppet?

Tags: debian, postgresql, puppet, debian-squeeze

I am using debian squeeze with PostgreSQL 9.1 from backports. Puppet has version 2.7.14.
Unfortunatly the init script returns the wrong exit code for status. Therefore I wrote a custom `status` command to detect whether postgresql is running or not.

```
service { 'postgresql':
  ensure => running,
  enable => true,
  hasstatus  => false,
  hasrestart => true,
  status => "pg_lsclusters -h | awk 'BEGIN {rc=0} {if ($4 != \"online\") rc=3} END { exit rc }'",
  provider => debian,
}
```

My command works like a charme, but puppet seems to have a problem. I always get `notice: /Stage[main]/Postgresql/Service[postgresql]/ensure: ensure changed 'stopped' to 'running'` although it is already running.

So tried the following:

```
service { 'postgresql':
  ensure => running,
  enable => true,
  hasstatus  => false,
  hasrestart => true,
  status => "exit 0",
  provider => debian,
}
```

As I understood this custom `status` command, puppet should always think that postgresql is running. Nevertheless puppet tries to start postgresql - every time.

What is my fault? Or is it a bug in puppet?

Comment: Your manifest looks correct, so this sounds like a bug in Puppet. It's a long shot, but try setting `provider => init` (and remove the `enable` parameter).

Comment: Are you sure exit 0 is a valid command?  The exit command is usually internal to a shell.  Do you need to do something like bash -c 'exit 0'?

Comment: @Zoredache you are right. With sh -c 'exit 0' the `status` command of puppet works as expected!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My best guesses are that the `$4` in your command is getting swallowed up by puppet's own interpolation and that `exit 0` doesn't quite work right due to shell interaction issues.

I would try a few things.

1. If the problem is puppet's interpolation on `$4` in your command escape the `$` like so:   `status => "pg_lsclusters -h | awk 'BEGIN {rc=0} {if (\$4 != \"online\") rc=3} END { exit rc }'"` (sometimes more backslashes are required, but I'm pretty sure 1 is enough here).
2. Make sure the test command is really working right. `exit` is a shell internal and I'm not sure how puppet will treat that. So use the canonical "return success" command instead: `status => "/bin/true"`
3. Maybe `status` is being overridden by `provider => debian` (which would be a puppet bug), so instead specify all the commands and use the base provider (this won't enable properly, however):

   ```
   service { 'postgresql':
     provider => base,
     ensure   => 'running',
     start    => '/etc/init.d/postgresql start',
     restart  => '/etc/init.d/postgresql restart',
     stop     => '/etc/init.d/postgresql stop',
     status   => "pg_lsclusters -h | awk 'BEGIN {rc=0} {if (\$4 != \"online\") rc=3} END { exit rc }'",
   }
   ```

Comment: One other thing: similar to the `exec` type, I think puppet needs full paths to executables.  Try setting those to the full path in your `status` line, if you haven't set one globally?

Comment: @ShaneMadden: Puppet doesn't necessarily need full paths to commands, though assuming it needs them doesn't hurt anything. In addition to a some sort of default path (PATH in environment daemon was started in?) `exec` accepts a `path` param and you can set a default path with `Exec { path => '/usr/bin:/bin' }` or `Exec { path => ['/usr/bin'],['/bin']}`. There's a similar 'path' on Service, but it appears to be primarily used with certain providers for finding init scripts, rather than as a normal shell-style command search path.

Comment: Thanks! The interpolation of `$4` was the problem. I replaced it with `\$4` and now everything works as expected :)